# Use of minio-java: "java.io.IOException: unexpected end of stream on"

Tags: java, minio

minio-java version：

```
8.3.1
```

minio version：

my config

```java
@Configuration(proxyBeanMethods = false)
public class MinioConfiguration {

    @Bean
    @SneakyThrows
    @ConditionalOnMissingBean(MinioClient.class)
    public MinioClient minioClient(MinioConfig ossProperties) {
        return MinioClient.builder()
                .endpoint(ossProperties.getEndpoint())
                .credentials(ossProperties.getAccessKey(), ossProperties.getSecretKey())
                .httpClient(newDefaultHttpClient())
                .build();
    }
    
    
    private OkHttpClient newDefaultHttpClient() {
        return new OkHttpClient()
                .newBuilder()
                .connectTimeout(10000, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
                .protocols(Arrays.asList(Protocol.HTTP_1_1))
                .retryOnConnectionFailure(true)
                .build();
    
    }
}
```

code

```java
@SneakyThrows 
public String uploadFile(InputStream inputStream, String bucketName, String path, String suffix) {
    boolean exists = minioClient.bucketExists(BucketExistsArgs.builder()
        .bucket(bucketName)
        .build());
    if (!exists) {
        minioClient.makeBucket(MakeBucketArgs.builder()
            .bucket(bucketName)
            .build());
        minioClient.setBucketPolicy(SetBucketPolicyArgs.builder()
            .bucket(bucketName)
            .config(config)
            .build());
    }
    String dateTime = LocalDateTime.now().format(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd"));

    String filePath = new StringBuilder()
        .append(path)
        .append(dateTime)
        .append("/")
        .append(IdUtil.fastSimpleUUID())
        .append(suffix)
        .toString();
    minioClient.putObject(PutObjectArgs.builder()
        .bucket(bucketName)
        .object(filePath)
        .stream(inputStream, inputStream.available(), -1)
        .build());
    return filePath;
}
```

The error: "java.io.IOException: unexpected end of stream on" when I run on the server, but not every time, only on the first connection after a long time of unconnection. Local operation is normal and there is no this phenomenon, I am a little confused.

I have tried joining retryOnConnectionFailure too but mini-java 8.3.1 does not allow PUT and POST does retryOnConnectionFailure operations.
Do I have any other solution.

I have tried joining retryOnConnectionFailure too but mini-java 8.3.1 does not allow PUT and POST does retryOnConnectionFailure operations.
Do I have any other solution.

Comment: Minio uses Docker container deployment

 版本：2022-07-04T21-2-54Z

Comment: ‘Unexpected end of stream on’ *what?*

Comment: The complete error message is' java. io. IOException: unexpected end of stream on ' http://172.17.0.1:9000/... “
The problem I identified was thrown by OkHttpClient
Among them, "172.17.0.1:9000" is the minio address I deployed in the container